# php with MSsql server

Tags: php, sql-server

i have placed both php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll&php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll  in the C:\xampp\php\ext folder
----------------------php.ini file--------------------------

```
extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
;extension=php_intl.dll
```

------------------------------connectionfile---------------------

```
<?php
$serverName="KEVONIA-PC\SQLEXPRESS";

$connecttioninfo=array("Database"=>"P_CAT_teetws");

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName,$connecttioninfo);
if( $conn ){
     echo "Connection Establised.<br/>";
    }else{
        echo "Connection not  Establised.<br/>";
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));
        }

?>
```

------------------------------loginexecfile---------------------

```
//Create query
    $qry="SELECT * FROM member WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $result=mssql_query($qry);

    //Check whether the query was successful or not
    if($result) {
        if(mssql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            //Login Successful
            session_regenerate_id();
            $member = mssql_fetch_assoc($result);
            $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['mem_id'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['username'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $member['password'];
            session_write_close();
            header("location: home.php");
            exit();
        }else {
            //Login failed
            $errmsg_arr[] = 'user name and password not found';
            $errflag = true;
            if($errflag) {
                $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
                session_write_close();
                header("location: index.php");
                exit();
            }
        }
    }else {
        die("Query failed");
```

### }

error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_query()

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find the full details for mssql_query: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php

But as your receiving undefined can you please check the php version and the mssql extention:

Create a info.php page and paste:

Here you can find more details:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc793139%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx

=== Personal Advice ===
My advice would be use MySQL with php, but that's your choice and depends on the requirements, but I do prefer php with MySQL and Asp.net with MSSQL.